# Huawei Ascend G630 shows on the display: "Recovery image verify failed"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, huawei

I've spent much time reading up on my issue with no progress at all.
I have a problem with a Huawei Ascend G630.

I have never rooting my phone or flashing a custom rom. The phone does not work, I can’t reset it by pressing volume up, down and power, and only when it’s on charge, it shows the message:

"Recovery image verify failed
Please update to the authorized images”.

I removed the battery, then, I tried getting it into the recovery mode to reset It or even flash its stock firmware following this instruction to solve it:

1)  I downloaded HUAWEI G630 Firmware from here:
http://consumer.huawei.com/kh/mobile-phones/support/downloads/detail/ascend-g630-kh.htm?id=26062

2)  I extracted Huawei Smartphone firmware (UPDATE.APP) on my PC and then I have pasted it on micro SD card.

The process doesn’t start and the phone returns to the first message
“Recovery image verify failed”.

I think that bootloader is locked.

I enclosed a picture.[image]

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and edit your question and delete your IMEI number... It is of no relevance to the issue and people steal these all the time.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it was important. Thank you.

Comment: IMEI, MEID, ESN, and serial numbers are all specific to a single device... Sharing them is not a good idea, people use them to clone devices. Other information like kernel, baseband, system, or build versions are fine, those are more generic and cover a variety of handsets in common.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite simple workaround to solve your problem.

- First you should search *(on XDA example)* and download an `original-recovery.bin` for your device.
- After you can flash it in `fastboot mode` with the following command:

  - **`fastboot flash recovery original-recovery.bin`**

After this you have an original bootloader on your device.

---

*Source: [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/ascend-g6/general/huawei-ascend-g6-u10-t3065963)*

Comment: I wrote:"fastboot flash recovery original-recovery.bin"
Prompt shows: “error: cannot load original-recovery.bin"; 
I downladed and extracted suggested file on XDA in a folder on my PC. 
So, I wrote this command:"fastboot reboot recovery.img",because in the folder called ADB that I downloaded, there are this file:
1)adb.exe;2)AdbWinApi.dll;3)AdbWinUsbApi.dll;4)boot.img;5)cwm.img;
6)fastboot.exe;7)recovery.img.

Comment: There was no such thing as a "suggested file on XDA", I just linked it as **SOURCE**. 
The file you've downloaded is for an other device (for Huawei Ascend G6-U10) not for your G630. I wrote in my answer in the very first step to download an original-recovery.bin **for your device**. Take an other round but in this time use a (device) correct original recovery. But I will edit my answer if it's not crystal clear to everyone.

Comment: I just tried to use this file, becauseI didn't foundthat for G630. When I wrote this command "fastboot reboot recovery.img", prompt shows "usage: fastboot [ <option> ] <command>" and it suggests to me some commands and options.

Comment: commands:
  update <filename>        flashall            flash <partition> [ <filename> ]             
  erase <partition>        getvar <variable>          boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]               
  flash:raw boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]        devices            continue                                  
  reboot         reboot-bootloader                           
options:
  -w    -s <serial number>     -p <product>       -c <cmdline>    -i <vendor id>                           
  -b <base_addr>           -n <page size>                       
According to you, what should I do now?

Comment: You can't use whichever device's recovery. You should find a proper recovery for your device. Use the search on XDA, or Google it. Further more your command is meaningless, to boot up your device into fastboot mode use this: `adb reboot-bootloader`.

Comment: I solved this problem after finding the right firmware (G630-U20 Firmware B127 European Android4.3 EMUI2.0Lite) for my device last week, and finally recovery has been successful.

Comment: I'm glad to help you out.